# jquery radio button selected still showing error

Tags: jquery

I've a radio button and on form submit I'm checking if it is selected , if not show error message. when clicked on radio button remove error message.
But even if radio button is selected it still returns true and shows error. Please help.
I tried debugging but because it's jquery control is going inside jquery library and it's hard to debug.

This is what I'm doing

```
$('input:radio').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#errgender').text("*");
});

$(':submit').on('click', function (e) {
    var valid = false;
    if (radio_not_selected) {
        valid = true;
        $('[name="gender"]').focus();
        $('#errgender').text("Please specify gender");
    }

    if (valid) e.preventDefault();
});

function radio_not_selected() {
    var radio = $("input[name='gender']:checked");
    if (radio.length <= 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, it sounds like you should really be using a checkbox, and not a radio button. Also, you can't start a condition with "else if" ?

Comment: What is `else` doing there? `else if (radio_not_selected) {`

Comment: sorry I've other conditions above it, which I excluded

Comment: This is gender that is why i'm using radio buttons

Comment: Well you need to call a function `if (radio_not_selected(/*pay attention*/)) {` not simply reference it.

Comment: Why on earth don't you just do `if ($("input[name='gender']:checked").length) {...` instead of calling another function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if (radio_not_selected) {
```

to:

```
if (radio_not_selected()) {
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. but why does it make difference, I've another function for checkbox and it's working perfectly fine without ().

Comment: Your version just tests whether the function exists, it doesn't actually run the function. It's basic Javascript syntax, similar to most programming languages: you have to put `()` after a function name to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your function. Change this:

```
if (radio_not_selected) {
```

to:

```
if (radio_not_selected()) {
```